# arr.splice() method deletes wrong item in react native project

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I was making a to-do app in react-native. I made a function that deletes the task on press but when I do press, it deletes the first item on the list, not the one I pressed on.
Here is the code I used:

```
 let id = 0;
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([
    { name: "Add your first task", id: id++ },
  ]);
  const handleTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTaskList([...taskList, { name: task, id: id++ }]);
    setTask("");
  };
  function completeTask(index) {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskList];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskList(itemsCopy);
  }
    {taskList.map((taskList, index) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                  <View style={styles.text}>
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={completeTask}>
                      <Text> {taskList.name} </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            })}
```

Comment: Can you debug it? What is the value of index, when you press?

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass index when call `completeTask` and update state wrond way.

```
onPress={() => completeTask(index)}

function completeTask(index) {
  setTaskList((preTasks) => preTasks.filter((item, i) => i !== index));
}
```

Comment: also, don't use `index` as `key` on the mapped item, use something unique e.g. an id

Comment: Exactle and we put `key` in the `View` right below `map`  instead in `TouchableOpacity`